# ADB not seeing HP 7 plus 1301

Tags: android

Adb is not seeing my HP 7 plus.

I am running Debian OS. My device is in development mode with USB debugging on.

How can I make adb see my device.

Comment: Did you check the udev rules are set up correctly?

Comment: I redid the udev rule but it still isn't showing up. Could you give me an example of what the rule should look like

Comment: I got it working was missing the vendor id in adb_usb.ini